# How do I create a local server / database cluster and disconnect remote servers using 5432 port?

Tags: postgresql

apologies if this has been asked before but all the answers I looked at didn't really work for me.

I'm on Postgres 15 on OSX Ventura 13, installed through EnterpriseDB. I usually connect to remote servers through the 5432 port to access my org's database but I need to set up a local server and database for a particular project. However, when I try to register a new server I get the below error. Do I have to change the port? If so, what do I change it to? I have also added an image of my config file.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I entered the following:

```bash
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data start
```

Result:

```
waiting for server to start....2023-10-16 19:58:09.418 EDT [86411] FATAL:  data directory "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/data" has invalid permissions
2023-10-16 19:58:09.418 EDT [86411] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
```

I've looked through a bunch of permissions related threads but can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: So, what's the answer to "is the server running" question in the error message? How did you verify that? What about the firewall blocking the specified port?

Comment: So I just now used pg_ctl status which said no server is running and then I tried to use pg_ctl start but then it said the server must be started by the user that owns the data directory - I'm not sure which one that is - do I just add sudo at the start of the command?

Comment: Tried putting sudo at the start of the command and it prompted me for a password, to which I put in my Mac password. This is the error I got: 
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.

Comment: `ls -l` (among other methods) will tell you who owns a directory.

Comment: thanks. I used `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data start` and it prompted me for the system password which I entered and then it said

could not identify current directory: Permission denied
could not identify current directory: Permission denied
could not identify current directory: Permission denied
program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the same directory as "pg_ctl"

Comment: which is weird because it definitely is - i see both pg_ctl and postgres in /Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin

Comment: @user274130 - Please add any new details to your question via the [edit] link just below the body of your question.

Comment: So, who owns `/Library/PostgreSQL/15/data`, and what are the permissions on the directory?

Comment: I think it was the company user on the remote server. Anyway, I ended up just creating a new data directory and it worked that way. Sorry for any confusion an thank you all for your time.